# PHP save values in memory

Tags: php, variables, memory, store

**Is it possible to save variables and values in PHP memory? if yes, how to do that?**

I want to have some values updated every 0.1 seconds (probably these values shouldn't be saved in a database because a mysqli query sometimes lasts longer than 0.1 second.)

Also i don't want to use $_SESSION because i want these variables accessable from all the users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), [shmop](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php), [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php), [redis](http://pecl.php.net/package/redis)

Comment: But how are you going to control updating every 0.1 seconds? Are you running a daemon process for this? Or can't you just calculated how many 0.1 second periods occur between requests and update accordingly only when required

Comment: executing ajax function every 0.1 seconds isn't a good idea?

Comment: @Liakos, where do you see ajax mentioned?

Comment: If every user viewing your page is sending 10 requests per second to the server then it isn't a good idea; it's a good way to swamp the server

Comment: no, i only need to change these values every 0.1 second. i will do that with an ajax function every 0.1 second from an admin panel. then i will create sockets so clients can see these values. is it good?

Comment: This isn't really a good approach if you need precise timing, network latency alone can affect it, as can a myriad other factors including your admin panel being closed: what's the real problem that you're trying to address. What are these values, why are they changing and what are the rules to change them?

Comment: It's like a game. a character has a position x0,y0 and he is ordered to move into a position x1,y1. every dt=0.1 seconds i need him to move over there updating his x0,y0 values. i really need to find a way to do this, if you can help i will appreciate this a lot.

Comment: Don't do it like this: you don't need real-time updates. Only calculate the position when you need to. If a character starts to move at 10:00:00.05 request time, and the next status request is at 10:01:15.07 then 75.2 seconds have elapsed and the character has moved 752 x/y steps... calculate the position at the point when you need it

Comment: If you have to do this "real time" then don't use an admin panel task issuing ajax requests, use a daemon process

Comment: hmmmm this was a great answer. made me think a lot. does dota, dota 2, league of legends work this way?

Comment: A daemon process is a process/program/script, typically started from the command line and running permanently on the server

Comment: which daemon tool you recommend me to use? now that you know my case

Comment: Daemons aren't "tools" They're scripts that you write to execute background processes (such as controlling character movement in this case)... you can write a daemon in php, or in C, or in ruby or python or perl

Comment: ok very nice. and how i write such script in php to control movement every 0.1 second? i use a loop function with sleep()?

Comment: Yes, and if you were running a daemon, then you could also provide socket connections that would allow your user processes to connect to the daemon to request information (character position) from it directly, and to submit character movement requests. You don't need to use shared memory or equivalent then, because the information is maintained in the daemon process memory itself, though persistence to a database would help preserve things in the event of a server crash or needing to restart the daemon process

Comment: god you are the best. you have 1000 times my thanks and my apologies for all this chatting. honor to england from greece. and to you,too. :))

Answer (score 0):

How about trying

1. using SQLite?
2. MongoDB, Redis?
3. Some other pure in memory datastore...

Comment: actually what im trying to do is to use a .txt file with the values stored there. is it going to be faster than any other fast-store method? what i need is speed, i may want to execute my function every 0.05 seconds instead of 0.1 later

Comment: If you need 0.05 second precision, you're working with real time and PHP isn't the right language for that type of work (nor is web the right medium)

Comment: For performance you may need to run the PHP script as a CLI, or write your appication using C / C++.

Comment: I have run applications which are as demanding as yours using PHP-CLI based script, it is processing AIS data from a worldwide feed and inserting to Mysql ISAM engine many requests per second on a single thread...

One other thing to note, you may still want to try using PHP from Apache and Mysql. You can try to benchmark your requests using JMeter, the result may surprise you.

Comment: PHP CLI means PHP Command Line Interface. This is a way of running PHP scripts in the system command line instead of web server, anyway the answer is irrelevant now based on your actual situation